# "ValueError: compile(): unrecognised flags" when running doctest on module using __future__.annotations

Tags: python, docker, pytest, doctest

I'm having a strange behavior, which I'm afraid is not easily reproducible. Maybe you can give me a hint..

On a Ubuntu 18.04 machine and inside a venv I'm running `pytest --doctest-modules` using Python 3.8.0 on a module which uses `__future__.annotations`

```
pipenv run pytest --doctest-modules my_module.py
```

without problems.

Now I'm running the same command inside a Docker environment (using `ubuntu:20.04`), mapping the directory containing the `.venv` folder. With the same Python version installed and no differences in the output of `pipenv graph` I'm getting an exception:

```
pipenv run pytest --doctest-modules my_module.py
____________________ [doctest] my_module _____________________________________

[some doctest code]

UNEXPECTED EXCEPTION: ValueError('compile(): unrecognised flags')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/doctest.py", line 1336, in __run
    exec(compile(example.source, filename, "single",
ValueError: compile(): unrecognised flags
/path/to/my_module.py:1234: UnexpectedException
```

I tried comparing `/usr/lib/python3.8/__future__.py` and the used `doctest.py` outside and inside the Docker environment, but they are identical (and they are also contained in the `.venv` directory anyway..).

I then tried to investigate on `compileflags` used in Doctests `exec(compile(...))` call and found that in one case (outside of Docker) it's `2^20` and in the other case it's `2^24`.

Digging deeper I found that *inside* the Docker-environment the `str()` value for `__future__.annotations` is

`_Feature((3, 7, 0, 'beta', 1), (3, 10, 0, 'alpha', 0), 16777216)`

while it's

`_Feature((3, 7, 0, 'beta', 1), (4, 0, 0, 'alpha', 0), 1048576)`

outside of the Docker container.

Why do I have those differences at all? And how can I make this Pytest-Test run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this *maybe* shouldn't have been backported in cpython 3.8 -- https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/19835

the flags changed in incompatible ways between 3.8.2 and 3.8.3, meaning if you have a pyc file from a newer version it will not work properly with the older version (despite being marked as compatible for cpython 3.8)

the patch linked above adjusted the flags to avoid collisions with other compiler flags